# How to scroll images vertically continuously using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for something similar to this http://maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/clickableLogoParade.htm

The current one is left to right.  But I need to scroll vertically ie bottom to top. Can any one help me plz

Comment: Are you certain you want that?  As a visitor to your site, I might be disappointed to see something like that.  (Just my $.02...)  IMHO there are so many cooler design "widgets" on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could tweak [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) to behave like you want.

- make it vertical
- make it circular
- set no delay
- turn off easing

Comment: I need similar to that link given above