# How to auto-scroll div content vertically continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to scroll the div which contains images, vertically. Any help or references will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean auto scroll?

Comment: Yes autoscroll without user interraction with loop like this http://maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/clickableLogoParade.htm  but vertically

Comment: Or try this plugin, You can customize it like you need :) [Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880470/how-to-scroll-images-vertically-continuously-using-jquery

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP I guess.

Comment: +1 Other SO question is about scrolling images - not a DIV, as question is.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9qC9E/8/) would help? First and last images are supposed to be the same.

JS:

```
(function(){
  var box=document.getElementById('box');
  box.appendChild(box.firstChild.cloneNode());    

  function infScroll(){
    box.scrollTop +=1;
    if(box.scrollTop===300){
        box.scrollTop=0;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(infScroll);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(infScroll);
}());
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box" style="width:150px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/90" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/120" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/80" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/90" />
</div>
```

Comment: how can i make that continously?