# How to scroll programmatically scroll? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to scroll to specific tab programmatically? I have here sample tabs created in [codepen](https://codepen.io/escbooster12-sun/pen/RwVyVKb).

I have visited this link but seems different in my case. [How to auto-scroll div content vertically continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880838/how-to-auto-scroll-div-content-vertically-continuously)

Is there a javascript, reactjs or any packages that can help achieve this? thanks

---

**Expected**: programmatically scroll to *"weather"* tab without scrolling by using `id` or `class`?

[image]

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 375px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" align="center">
  <div class="navbar flex">
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="trending">Trending</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="health">Health</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="technology">Technology</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="business">Business</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="sport">Sports</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="weather">Weather</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="entertainment">Entertainment</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="world">World</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="local">Local</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="covid">Covid-19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need a horizontal scrolling solution, not a vertical one. right?

Comment: without scrolling by using `id` or `class`, then how would do target the desired element?

Comment: @HamzaIftikhar sorry its horizontal i mean. sorry. I updated the title

Comment: Do you want to scroll using mouse wheel or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the element's [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function.

In vanilla JS it would look like this for example:
`document.querySelector('#sport').scrollIntoView();`

With react instead of querying a selector with the document, you should create a ref to the element instead. Read through [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) if you're unsure how that works.

Edit: If you want it to be in the middle of your view, you can pass an options object to `scrollIntoView` like this:
`...scrollIntoView({ inline: "center" });`

Comment: "*without scrolling by using id or class*"; `#sport` is the id,

Comment: it works but is it possible to make it in the middle. to be able to show next tab. like in the picture.

Comment: @0stone0 ahh yes. it still scroll. hmm...

Comment: thanks, I think this meets in my app spec. however the comment of @0stone0 has point.

Comment: If you read through the article i linked, you can find out how to get a reference of the element without using its ID. (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```js
const e = document.getElementById('sport');
e.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'auto',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 375px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" align="center">
  <div class="navbar flex">
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="trending">Trending</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="health">Health</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="technology">Technology</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="business">Business</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="sport">Sports</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="weather">Weather</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="entertainment">Entertainment</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="world">World</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="local">Local</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="covid">Covid-19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you've provided gives you a hint on what to do.  In that example, the div is programmatically scrolled by using the `scrollTop` property.  In your case, you'd want to use its sibling, the `scrollLeft` property.  This property will programmatically scroll an element that has an overflow to the left by the specified amount.

[Mozilla documentation of scrollLeft property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft)

I've updated your code to include an example:

```js
let el = document.getElementById("navbar");
el.scrollLeft = 350;
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 375px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" align="center">
  <div class="navbar flex" id="navbar">
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="trending">Trending</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="health">Health</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="technology">Technology</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="business">Business</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="sport">Sports</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="weather">Weather</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="entertainment">Entertainment</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="world">World</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="local">Local</div>
    <div class="tab flex items-center justify-center" id="covid">Covid-19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we go to specific tab by use of `id` prop?

Comment: Yes, see @Gergely Kovács' answer below, except add {inline: "center"} between the parentheses. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView for more info.